# read files and read directory in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, callback, fs, async.js

I want to know whtether the read file and read directory functions - fs.readdir(path, callback) and fs.readFile(path, options, callback) have similar functions without callback.Here, I first read all the files in given directory, and loop through all the files and upload their content to S3 bucket.
Please see the working code below.

```
const s3Upload = async (req, res) => {
  const directoryName = "MAXIS_GAMING/Daily/"
  var data = {}
  let files = {}
  await readFiles1(directoryName)
  }
  
  const readFiles1 = async(dirname) => {
    let _files
    fs.readdir(dirname, (err, files) => {
      // On error, show it and return
      if(err) return console.error(err);
    
      // files is an array containing the names of all entries
      // in the directory, excluding '.' (the directory itself)
      // and '..' (the parent directory).
    
      // Display directory entries
      console.log(files.join(' '));
      files.forEach(function(filename){
        fs.readFile(dirname + filename, 'utf-8', function(err, content){
          if(err) {
           // onError(err);
           throw err
            return;
          }
          console.log('cont..............................',content)
          console.log('filename', filename)
          //await 
          uploadFiles(filename, content)
          //onFileContent(filename, content);
        })
      })
  
    })
  
  }
  
  const uploadFiles = async (fileName, fileContent) => {
    console.log('in uploadd..........')
    const GLOBAL_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'AKIDAQWZX6B3XUBDIFHLPC5LYFTJF15XPIQ';
    const GLOBAL_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'Sv4Fe4h4QgErG5XoZbgeC63oczkdW3bMQfC0jvyR8bPbJ9Y97k+'
    const GLOBAL_DEFAULT_REGION = 'ap-southeast-1';
    const S3_IMAGE_BUCKET ='max-stg-image/stage/reports'//"max-stg-image";
    const S3_IMAGE_PATH =  "stage";
      
    AWS.config.update({
          accessKeyId: GLOBAL_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
          secretAccessKey: GLOBAL_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
          region: GLOBAL_DEFAULT_REGION,
    });
      
    const s3 = new AWS.S3()
    const bucket = new AWS.S3()
    const params = {
        Bucket: S3_IMAGE_BUCKET,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: fileContent
    };
    
    // Uploading files to the bucket
    s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
              throw err;
          }
          console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
    });
  }

  app.get('/home/s3Upload', s3Upload)
```

Comment: Not sure what you're really asking for.  There's `fs.readdirSync()` and `fs.readFileSync()`, but neither of those should be used in a server (except in startup code) because they block the event loop and destroy server scalability.  There's also `fs.promises.readdir` and `fs.promises.readFile` which are both still asynchronous, but they return a promise instead of use a plain callback.

Comment: Also, please NEVER write `if (err) { throw err; }` inside an asynchronous handler inside an http server route handler.  You need to write real error handling that sends an error response, not throw asynchronously which will not do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import { readdir } from 'fs/promises';
//or with require

const readdir = require('fs/promises').readdir;

try {
  const files = await readdir(path);
  for (const file of files)
    console.log(file);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Check [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options) all the promise API provided by FS in Node.js.